# why does R markdown says that the column is not found?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyverse, read.csv

I am trying to create a table in R, but it says there is no such column.
Here is what  I have done:

```
invis_tib <- readr::read_csv("/Users/bahar/Desktop/yeni_r/veri/invisibility.csv")
─ Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

cols(
`id;cloak;mischief` = col_character()
)

```
``{r,echo=FALSE}
invis_sum <-invis_tib %>%
dplyr::group_by(cloak) %>%
dplyr::summarize(
n=n(),
mean=mean(mischief),
`std.dev` =sd(mischief)

)

Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`. * Column `cloak` is not found.
```

Please help me to get handle this.

Someone commented use csv2, so I tried and got this:

```
``ℹ Using ',' as decimal and '.' as grouping mark. Use     `read_delim()`       for more control.

── Column specification   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
cols(
id = col_double(),
cloak = col_character(),
mischief = col_double()
)

[1] "id"       "cloak"    "mischief"
```

But when I run the code for the mean and sd nothing happens, when I knit I just get ...

Comment: Try with `read::read_csv2`. Looks like the separator of your csv is a semicolon ";" so that all your columns are glued together into one with name `id;cloak;mischief`

Comment: What does it say when you do `colnames(invis_tib)`? You may need to add `HEADER = TRUE` when you load the `.csv` into R.

Comment: Wow. It kinds of worked.  Using ',' as decimal and '.' as grouping mark. Use `read_delim()` for more control.

── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
cols(
  id = col_double(),
  cloak = col_character(),
  mischief = col_double()
)         but nothing comes up at the summary?

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I changed my data. It was just like you said. There were semi-colons instead of commas. So I changed them by hand, and it all resolved.